# Not able to skip attachment processing while reading inbox from email using "imap"

Tags: javascript, node.js, imap, email-parsing, node-imap

I'm using npm library **imap** to fetch inbox of email as follows:

```
readMails(path, skip, limit){
        return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
            let mails = [], total;

            this.imap.once('ready', (err) =>{
                this.imap.openBox(path, false, (err, box)=>{
                        total = box.messages.total;

                        if(total<limit) return this.imap.end();

                        var f = this.imap.seq.fetch(`${skip+1}:${limit}`, {
                            bodies: [''],
                            struct: true
                        });
                        f.on('message', (msg, seqno) => {
                            let buffer = '', mail = { content: null, attrs: null }; 

                            console.log('Message #%d', seqno);
                            var prefix = '(#' + seqno + ') ';
                            msg.on('body', (stream, info) => {
                                //console.log(stream)
                                let chunk = ''
                                stream.on('data',(chunk)=>{
                                    buffer += chunk.toString('utf8')
                                })
                            });
                            msg.once('attributes', (attrs) => {
                                mail.attrs = attrs
                            console.log(prefix + 'Attributes: %s', attrs, false, 8);
                            });
                            msg.once('end', () => {
                                console.log(prefix + 'Finished');
                                simpleParser(buffer, (err, content)=>{
                                    console.log(err, mail);
                                    let {date,from,html,messageId,subject,text,textAsHtml} = content;
                                    mail.content = {date,from,html,messageId,subject,text,textAsHtml};  
                                    mails.push(mail);
                                })
                            });
                        });
                        f.once('error', (err) => {
                            console.log('Fetch error: ' + err);
                        });
                        f.once('end', () => {
                            console.log('Done fetching all messages!');
                            this.imap.end();
                        });
                })
            });
            this.imap.once('error', function(err) {
                reject()
                console.log(err);
            });

            this.imap.once('end', function() {
                resolve({ mails, total });
                console.log('Connection ended');
            });

            this.imap.connect();
        })
    }
```

Which gives desired output but it takes too much time to load since it processes its attachment as well.

I'm wondering if there is any way to skip attachment download and processing which will save too much time on server.

Comment: Your code explicitly requests the body '', which is the entire message.

Comment: Only with a large amount of complexity.  You would need to fetch the BODYSTRUCTURE for all your messages, then figure out where the body section is, whatever you consider that to be, and fetch only that.  Unless your connection is slow, or mobile, the added round trips may actually take longer than downloading the occasional attachment.

Comment: @max: He is asking for the struct. His requests are UID FETCH 123:456 (BODY[] BODYSTRUCTURE).